Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
hello i have a next trouble:
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : name
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /AcademicGroup/students/name
line number         : -1
class[1]            : AcademicGroup
required-type[1]    : AcademicGroup
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.20
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:499)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:425)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1464)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1441)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1407)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1352)
    at AcademicGroupJSONDeserialization.main(AcademicGroupJSONDeserialization.java:14)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: name
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readBareItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:131)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:117)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:99)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:92)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:86)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
    ... 16 more

Process finished with exit code 1

I'm trying to deserialize the next json.file:
{"AcademicGroup": {
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Smith",
      "age": 22
    }
  ]
}}

I have a task to do deserialising from json file but can't do it. I'm using the next code to serialize and deserialize:
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class AcademicGroupSerialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AcademicGroup academicGroup = new AcademicGroup();
        Student student1 = new Student("John Doe", 20);
        Student student2 = new Student("Jane Smith", 22);
        academicGroup.addStudent(student1);
        academicGroup.addStudent(student2);

        // Serializing to xml
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.alias("AcademicGroup", AcademicGroup.class);
        String xml = xStream.toXML(academicGroup);
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("AcademicGroup.xml"); PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw)) {
            out.println(xml);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Serializing to JSON
        xStream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver());
        xStream.alias("AcademicGroup", AcademicGroup.class);
        String json = xStream.toXML(academicGroup);
        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("AcademicGroup.json");
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw)) {
            out.println(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


To deserialize:
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.json.JettisonMappedXmlDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.AnyTypePermission;

import java.io.File;

public class AcademicGroupJSONDeserialization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
        xStream.addPermission(AnyTypePermission.ANY);

        xStream.alias("AcademicGroup", AcademicGroup.class);

        AcademicGroup academicGroup = (AcademicGroup) xStream.fromXML(new File("AcademicGroup.json"));
        System.out.println(academicGroup);
    }
}

The classes codes:
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AcademicGroup {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student.AcademicGroup{" +
                "students=" + students +
                '}';
    }
}
public class Student {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Геттеры и сеттеры
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}

i have no troubles with deserializing from xml but have troubles with json. help please.

Your POJO class is not compatible of your sample JSON if want to deserialize, you have to add 1 more abstraction POJO at top of AcademicGroup like below
public class TopJsonObject
{
    @JsonProperty("AcademicGroup")
    private AcademicGroup academicGroup;

    public AcademicGroup getAcademicGroup()
    {
        return academicGroup;
    }

    public void setAcademicGroup(AcademicGroup academicGroup)
    {
        this.academicGroup = academicGroup;
    }
}

Also notice you're providing "AcademicGroup" with capital letter in your JSON but JSON serialiser will not pick this, if you really want Capital letter in JSON, you have to use @JsonProperty("AcademicGroup") annotation in your POJO. Otherwise change your "AcademicGroup" alias with "academicGroup". You can refer below code
// Existing code
xStream.alias("AcademicGroup", AcademicGroup.class); 
// Need to change with below line
xStream.alias("academicGroup", AcademicGroup.class);

